# giving 2 outputs in while loop in c

Tags: c, while-loop, do-while

I was trying to write a code to use instead of using goto and I wrote this one.
When I made this code run:

```
int main()
{
    int a;
    printf ("1 or 2");
    scanf ("%d", &a);
    if (a == 1)
    {
        return card();
    }
    else
        return computer();
}

int computer(void)
{
    char c;
    int f = 0 ;
    do
    {
        printf ("choose y or n\n");
        scanf ("%c", &c);

        switch (c)
        {
            case 'y':
                card();
                break;
            case 'n':
                main();
                break;
        }

    }
    while(f<1);

    return 0;
}
int card(void)
{
    char d;
    int e = 1;
    do
    {
        printf ("chhose y or n2\n");
        scanf ("%c", &d);

        switch (d)
        {
            case 'y':
                computer();
                break;
            case 'n':
                main();
                break;
        }
    }
    while(e<2);

    return 0;
}
```

its out put is being like:

```
1 or 2 2
choose y or n
choose y or n
```

printing same thing for 2nd time. I tried to change while loop for different styles or algorithms but I couldnt find a useful solution. Im really new at coding so Im really out of ideas

Comment: Recursively calling `main` is usually not a good idea. Having a main loop in the `main` function is much better.

Comment: As for your problem. When you give input you end the input with the enter key. This key is stored in the input buffer as a newline (`'\n'`), and when you read a character after reading the number you get this newline. Add a space in the format string before `"%c"` to discard the newline.

Comment: Calling `main` in `card`, that was called from `main` is a hidden recursion - be careful, and do not do that. Functions that are called from `main` should use `return` for returning to `main`

Comment: The do while loop `while(f<1);` will run infinitely, as you are not incrementing `f`

Comment: A general note: if you expect user to give response to a single question and press enter, then you should read a line (using `fgets` if you can only use C standard library, or better `getline` if it is available in your OS), then parse it (possibly with `sscanf`, or just examining it in `for` loop). `scanf` is not ideal for line based input.

Answer (score 0):

I've always had problems with **%c** myself. Try doing the following

```
int computer(void)
{
   char c[3];
   int f = 0 ;
   do
   {
      printf ("choose y or n\n");
      scanf ("%s", c);

      switch (c[0])
      {
        case 'y':
            card();
            break;
        case 'n':
            main();
            break;
      }

   }while(f<1);

   return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

**Bad practices**

- I can see that "e" and "f" variables are never incremented or assigned any other value. So, its an infinite loop.
- calling main() recursively is a bad practice

burakozgul has correctly identified the actual problem. If you only scan one character, that's what you get and then the next scanf() call will return the newline or whatever character in the buffer!

So, I think User_Targaryen's solution to use scanf(%s, &c) is better. But, you may possibly want to use getchar() function.

Answer (score -2):

You are reading newline character too. To ignore newline character read newline to another char.

```
char c,ignore;
scanf ("%c%c", &c,&ignore);
```

like that.

Comment: ...of course if user enters anything except single character followed by return, this will not work.

Comment: It's a example, I did not handle error conditions :( @hyde

Comment: (I feel the need to note, that those are not my downvotes)

Comment: It's better to use scanf (" %c",&c);

Comment: @hyde it's not problem :) I'm new here, if guys show the correct way to do this. I will learn too.